# How to stop someone from accessing a file outside an iframe?

Tags: .htaccess, iframe

I´m using an iframe to show an one course on my page.

The files for the online course is located in http://www.domain.com/coursefiles and the iframe looks like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.domain.com/coursefiles/index.php" width="100%" height="670"></iframe>
```

Now, does anyone know any htaccess command on how I can deny direct access to the course folder, but let the users only access it trough the page with the iframe?

"sorry for the bad english" :)

Comment: you mean, you want to disable the directory indexing?

Comment: not really. More like disabling the possibility to acccess index.html in that folder, but still access it from the iframe

Comment: Can't do that in any secure way. The web doesn't work like that. You can try what Jon Lin suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The webserver has no way to know whether a page was requested inside an iframe or not, other than using the **Referer:** header, which can be spoofed. But you can do that pretty easily by putting this in the htaccess file in the `/coursefiles/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !www\.domain\.com/page-where-iframe-is.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

So unless the referer contains a `www.domain.com/page-where-iframe-is.html` in it, access to this directory will be forbidden.