# How to add this exception to htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, security, iframe

I have this course created with software called Articulate Storyline, which from there you can export as html5. An LMS plugin on my site manages access to the course, and the html5 export is included there as an iframe. To prevent access to the html5 export from outside the LMS I added an htaccess file to the server folder with the html5 export, in line with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12393526).

Exported course files are in: `/public_html/courses/course_a/` (there are multiple courses).
Course url: `https://example.com/coursename/courseA/` (which has an iframe that points to `https://example.com/courses/course_a/story.html`).

I created `/public_html/courses/.htaccess` with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !\example\.com/coursename/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

It all works except that if you load the course there are the following 403 errors in the console:

```
GET https://example.com/courses/course_a/html5/lib/stylesheets/mobile-fonts/open-sans-light.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 403 desktop.min.css:1 
GET https://example.com/courses/course_a/html5/lib/stylesheets/mobile-fonts/open-sans-regular.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 403 desktop.min.css:1 
GET https://example.com/courses/course_a/html5/lib/stylesheets/mobile-fonts/open-sans-bold.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 403 desktop.min.css:1
```

I think the .htaccess files I added causes this. Is there a way to create an exception in the .htaccess file for the `/mobile-fonts/` folder or for woff files?

---

**Update:** I updated `/public_html/courses/.htaccess` to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example\.com/coursename/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example\.com/courses/
RewriteRule ^ - [F,END]
```

However, I now get a 403 error both for `https://example.com/coursename/courseA/` (403 for the iframe) and for `https://example.com/courses/course_a/story.html`. For the second, I indeed want a 403 but not for the first.

If I remove `[OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example\.com/courses/` then `https://example.com/coursename/courseA/` works and does not return a 403. But then I can even change the first RewriteCond to `!^https://example\.com/coursename/fhwfhf` and it still loads the iframe...

Comment: You should add the site displayed in the iframe itself as additional possible referer. Because it is _that_ site that fetches additional things like fonts, css and js in background.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. I'm afraid I really don't know much of htaccess. Would you be able to provide an example of how to change the htaccess file to achieve as you suggest?

Comment: You can simply chain multiple `RewriteCond` directives one after another. The default is a logical "and" combination, but you can change that to a logical "or" by using the `[OR]` flag following the first condition. The documentation clearly demonstrates that: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. If I add `OR %{HTTP_REFERER} !\example\.com/folder-that-iframe-points-to/ [NC]`, then a user can go to that url and view the content of the iframe. The whole reason for the htaccess file was to prevent that behaviour; i.e., to force a user to only view that content via the LMS (which manages access to that content). So that doesn't solve it for me. Perhaps add woff files as an exception for the htaccess file?

Comment: Is that so? Did you test that? If someone directly enters that URL into a browser, then _no_ http referrer should be set...

Comment: I added an answer below sketching the options that come into my mind...

Comment: Thanks, I had indeed tested, but with a different syntax such as `[OR]` without brackets: `OR`. Strangely enough, this did not return an internal server error. But I've been unable to recreate that situation since.

Comment: I made a comment to my answer below which explains why the `[OR]` operator is indeed wrong here. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments to the question one approach is to add the URL of the "page" loaded into that iframe itself to your condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example\.com/url-that-includes-the-iframe
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example\.com/folder-that-iframe-points-to
RewriteRule ^ - [F,END]
```

A directly entered URL pointing to `https://example\.com/folder-that-iframe-points-to` should not have a referer set at all, so I would expect such request to get blocked...

---

Another approach would be to explicitly allow access to resources referenced by the "page" delivered into the iframe. This can be done by adding such an exception *before* the actual blocking rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?html5/lib/stylesheets/ - [END]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example\.com/url-that-includes-the-iframe
RewriteRule ^ - [F,END]
```

Or, alternatively, the same can also be achieved by adding that exception to the condition of the actual blocking rule. Note that this variant does *not* specify an `[OR]` operand, the default logical "and" operator is what needs to get applied:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example\.com/url-that-includes-the-iframe
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/html5/lib/stylesheets/
RewriteRule ^ - [F,END]
```

---

For all of these approaches the rewriting module needs to be loaded and activated into the http server. The rules are best placed into the actual host configuration inside the http server. Without access to that a distributed configuration file can be used (".htaccess"), but that comes with some disadvantages and requires the interpretation of such files to be enabled (see the documentaton for that...).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my post with the result.

Comment: Sorry, my logic had been asleep. Since we are talking about negated conditions a logical "AND" is what should get used. Not a logical "or". So you do not have to specify a flag at all, since "and" is the default. I updated the answer.

Comment: Great! It now indeed works! Just a heads up for anyone else with a similar situation: When directly going to the iframe url, it sometimes for me loaded the content instead of giving a 403. When refreshing, it would then give the 403. Apparently, it sometimes loaded the content from cache, which was created when visiting the course from the LMS url.

Comment: Sure, caching always is something one has to keep in mind when adjusting request handling.